# Data Label is not working using Syncfusion chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

I've been trying to add a data label on my bar chart using Syncfusion. However it doesn't display on the top of the data series but when I used tooltip it shows the data label. I wondered what could be the problem that blocks the data label to display in the chart. Here's my code

```html
CSHTML FILE

<div class="box box-default">
<div class="box-body">
            @Html.EJS().Chart("container").Series(
            sr =>
           {
            sr.XName("Name").YName("Loan").Name("Loan Risk").Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ChartSeriesType.Column).DataSource(ViewBag.dataSource).Add();
            sr.XName("Name").YName("Score").Name("Loan Score").Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ChartSeriesType.Column).DataSource(ViewBag.dataSource).Add();
            sr.Marker(mr => mr.DataLabel(dl => dl.Visible(true).Position(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.LabelPosition.Top).Font(ff => ff.FontWeight("600").Color("#ffffff")))).DataSource(ViewBag.dataSource).Name("Users").Add();
                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                    
            }).PrimaryYAxis(px => px.LabelFormat("p1").LabelStyle(ls => ls.Color("#21130d")).LineStyle(ls => ls.Width(0)).MajorTickLines(mg => mg.Width(0))
            .MajorGridLines(mg => mg.Width(0))
            ).PrimaryXAxis(px => px.LabelIntersectAction(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.LabelIntersectAction.Hide).Interval(1)
            .ValueType(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ValueType.Category).MajorGridLines(mg => mg.Width(0))).Tooltip(tt => tt.Enable(true)
            ).ChartArea(area => area.Border(br => br.Color("transparent"))
            ).LegendSettings(lg => lg.Visible(true)).Title("Pre - Funding Audit Report").Render()

</div>
</div>
```

[Here's my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsbe8.jpg)

[This is the layout that I want (The Data label is at the top of the Data Series)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrInN.jpg)

Comment: I resolved it! 
Answer: 

 sr.Marker(mr => mr.Visible(true).DataLabel(dl => dl.Visible(true))).XName("SumGr_QC_Borrower_Name").YName("SumGr_QC_Loan_Risk").Name("Loan Risk").Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ChartSeriesType.Column).DataSource(ViewBag.dataSource).Add();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since data label position is outer and font color is white, data label is not visible in white background. We request you to change the color of data label.

UG : https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/documentation/chart/data-labels/

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion.

We have created a simple MVC application using the provided details with the latest version(v20.3.47) to replicate the reported scenario. But we are unable to reproduce the same. Please find the below-tested sample link for your reference.

Sample link: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/BarchartDatalabel1560960055

Code Snippet:

```
series =>
            {
                series.Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ChartSeriesType.Column).Name("Imports").XName("x").YName("y")
                .Marker(mr => mr.DataLabel(dl => dl.Visible(true).Position(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.LabelPosition.Top).Font(ff => ff.FontWeight("600").Color("#ffffff"))))
                .DataSource(ViewBag.dataSource).Add();
                series.Type(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.ChartSeriesType.Column).Name("Exports").XName("x").YName("y")
                .Marker(mr => mr.DataLabel(dl => dl.Visible(true).Position(Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.LabelPosition.Top).Font(ff => ff.FontWeight("600").Color("#ffffff"))))
                .DataSource(ViewBag.dataSource1).Add();
            })
```

If the reported scenario still persists, please modify the above sample to replicate the reported scenario. It will be helpful for us to analyze further and assist you better.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don’t include signatures in answers; all posts are tagged with your account, so a signature is extraneous. Further, I’ve formatted your code; please review the formatting options so you can format future code.